# Differentiation of $a^\top x x^\top a$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I know that for matrix $A$ and vector $x$, the derivative of the quadratic form with respect to $x$ is

$$\frac{\partial x^TAx}{\partial x} = (A+A^T)x$$

But how do we differentiate $a^T x x^T a$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: You have a bit of a problem: the function you're trying to differentiate has a vector as its input and a matrix as an output.  There is no traditional way to express the derivative of such a function as a vector or matrix.

Comment: My bad. A is a (1,n) matrix in this case

Comment: Did you mean that $A$ is an $n \times 1$ matrix?  As the function is currently written, $A$ and $x$ should be the same kind of vector, if they are both vectors

Comment: Yes, sorry, $n x 1$

Comment: Why would it not work if A would be (1,n)? We would have A^T (n,1), x (1,n) etc.

Comment: $A^T$ would be $n \times 1$, and $x$ is $n \times 1$.  You can't multiply two vectors of the same shape.

Comment: But the inner-product is defined as an operation on inputs of equal dimensionality?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are $n \times 1$ vectors, then $xy$ is not defined.  Their dot-product, $x^Ty$, makes perfect sense.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what is going on here. $x^TAx$ is what precisely in case that $A$ is $n\times 1$ matrix? There is associativity issue here: $$\langle A, x\rangle x^T=x^T(Ax)=x^TAx = (x^TA)x = \langle A, x\rangle x.$$

Comment: This only makes sense when $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix and $x$ is $n\times 1$ vector.

Comment: @Ennar the asker incorrectly assumed that these two functions were related

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, huh, guess so.

Comment: huh - edited...

Comment: For the edited question, the function can be rearranged $$a^Txx^Ta=x^Taa^Tx=x^TAx$$ so that identifying $A=aa^T$ allows you to use the known result.  Not only that, but this particular $A$ is symmetric, which allows the known result to be simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Noting that $A^Tx = x^TA \in \Bbb R$, we can rewrite 
$$
A^TxxA^T = (A^Tx)^2
$$
an appropriate "chain rule" will work here.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathrm a^\top \mathrm x$ is a scalar and scalar multiplication is commutative,

$$\nabla_{\mathrm x} \left( \mathrm a^\top \mathrm x \mathrm x^\top \mathrm a \right) = \nabla_{\mathrm x} \left( \mathrm x^\top \mathrm a \mathrm a^\top \mathrm x \right) = \color{blue}{2 \,\mathrm a \mathrm a^\top \mathrm x}$$

because rank-$1$ matrix $\mathrm a \mathrm a^\top$ is symmetric.

---

[matrix-calculus](/questions/tagged/matrix-calculus) [scalar-fields](/questions/tagged/scalar-fields) [gradient](/questions/tagged/gradient)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean $a^{T}xx^{T}a=(a^{T}x)(x^{T}a)=(a^{T}x)(a^{T}x)^{T}={(a^{T}x)}^{2}.$ You're placement of the transpose operator needs adjustment. This is because $a,x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$ implies $a^{T}x\in\mathbb {R}$. Also, using the uppercase $A$ makes it seem like $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ in which case $A^{T}x\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$ and ${(A^{T}x)}^2$ is only well-defined if and only if $m=1$.